# Issue with FB graph api whilst reading files from AWS S3 Mumbai region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3

I'm facing an issue with AWS S3 Mumbai region. Please refer the link [FB Graph API has trouble pulling images from AWS S3 Mumbai region](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=831509#831509) for more details.

FB support team responded stating the issue isn't on their side.  AWS team is yet to respond.

Is anyone in this forum encountered similar issue?  If so, has it been resolved?  Pls share some pointers.

Comment: Do you see attempts to access the image in your bucket logs?

Comment: Yes. in fact, from the same folder I was able to share smaller size images on FB.  Basically, I used FB Graph explorer for this trial.  It pulls the files of size < 1 MB.  However, it fails if the file size is > 1 MB.